# Assign object {row} to state

Tags: react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to migrate my application which currently uses react-bootstrap-table to react-bootstrap-table-next but I'm having a problem.

**What I am trying to do:**

is to get the object of the selected line.

**My code**

```
const selectRow = {
        mode: 'radio',
        hideSelectColumn: true,
        clickToSelect: true,
        bgColor: 'red',
        onSelect: (row) => {
           console.log(row)
          }
      };

<div className="col-lg-12">
                             <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ products } columns={ columns } selectRow={ selectRow }   />
                        </div>
```

**result obtained**

When I click on the line, it assigns the color red and prints the object to the selected line

but when I try to put the object in the state:

```
const selectRow = {
        mode: 'radio',
        hideSelectColumn: true,
        clickToSelect: true,
        bgColor: 'red',
        onSelect: (row) => {
           console.log(row)
           this.setState({banco: row});
          }
      };
```

The selected line object is assigned to {banco} property as expected, but the line does not turn red.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check [this](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/297). As the above link mention, right now there's only one workaround is when you need to call `setState` in `selectRow.onSelect`, please also manage the selection by yourself via `selectRow.selected` I'm the creator of `react-bootstrap-table` and we will improve this issue in the future. Please follow above link to have a workaround, thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20270411)

Comment: As the above link mention, right now there's only one workaround is when you need to call `setState` in `selectRow.onSelect`, please also manage the selection by yourself via `selectRow.selected`